# When I click on a button it should select certain items according to the condition

Tags: java, swing

I have one combo box,a jbutton and some labels.

When in the combo box **item 1** is selected and i press okay(j button) it should change the color of some labels not all the labels(i.e. label 1, label 5 and label 3).

And when **item 2** in combo box is selected it should change the color of label(2,4,6).

What should i do?

What condition i should apply?

Comment: You should post relevant code...

Answer (score 1):

> "What should i do?"

Add an `ItemListener` to the  combobox, and use `label.setForeground(color);` or `label.setBackgound(color);`, depending on what which you want changed.

> "What condition i should apply?"

```
String selection = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
if ("blue".equals(slection)) {
    label.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
}
```

---

This may not be what you want exactly, but you haven't explained much or show what you have attempted. I *can* say that this seems like a rather simple and basic GUI task. If it is troubling you, I suggest you go though [**How to create GUIs with Swing**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)